# Don't want "close" button to move when resizing window

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, positioning

I have a popup window that appears when clicking on a link that I would like to have a close button rather then clicking off screen.
I implemented said close button except I can't get it to stay still when resizing the screen. I would like it to stay put at the top right of the popup window, half on and half off of it.

I've tried moving it inside and outside of the divs but if I move it inside, it will get cut off if I try to position it "half on and half off"

I've attached a screen shot of where I am trying to get it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/o33Qw.jpg

```
<p><a class="show-popup" href="#">TBLO (Tibial Plateau Leveling Osteotomy)</a></p>

<div class="overlay-bg2">
   <div class="close-btn-wrapper">
     <button class="close-btn2"><strong>X</strong></button>
   </div> 
     <div class="overlay-content2">

 <p>CONTENT ENTERED HERE</p>
 <button class="close-btn">Close</button>
</div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.overlay-bg2 {
z-index: 1801;
display: none;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height:100%;
width: 100%;
cursor: pointer;
background: #000; /* fallback */
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.overlay-content2 {
z-index: 1800;
background: #fff;
padding: 1%;
width: 700px;
height: 200px;
overflow:auto;
position: relative;
top: 15%;
left: 30%;
margin: 0 0 0 -10%; /* add negative left margin for half the width to center the div */
cursor: default;
border-radius: 4px;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}

.close-btn-wrapper {
   position:relative;
   width: 400px;
   left:25%;
   z-index: 2001;

    }

.close-btn2 {
cursor: pointer;
border: 1px solid #333;
background: #a9e7f9; /* fallback */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a9e7f9 0%, #77d3ef 4%, #05abe0 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#a9e7f9),          
color-stop(4%,#77d3ef), color-stop(100%,#05abe0));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a9e7f9 0%,#77d3ef 4%,#05abe0 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #a9e7f9 0%,#77d3ef 4%,#05abe0 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #a9e7f9 0%,#77d3ef 4%,#05abe0 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #a9e7f9 0%,#77d3ef 4%,#05abe0 100%);
border-radius: 4px;
box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
position: absolute;
top:30px;
right: 180px;
z-index: 2000;
padding: 1% 1%;
}

.close-btn2:hover {
background: #05abe0;
}
```

and JS (if it matters)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// show popup when you click on the link

$('.show-popup').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault(); // disable normal link function so that it doesn't refresh the page
$(this).parent().next().show(); //display your popup
});

// hide popup when user clicks on close button
$('.close-btn').click(function(){
$('.overlay-bg2').hide(); // hide the overlay
});

// hides the popup if user clicks anywhere outside the container
$('.overlay-bg2').click(function(){
    $('.overlay-bg2').hide();
})
// prevents the overlay from closing if user clicks inside the popup overlay
$('.overlay-content2').click(function(){
    return false;
});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below CSS. I had made some changes to you styles, have commented all the changes. Change the values as you need.
Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/GnE3T/)

CSS used:

```
.overlay-bg2 {
    z-index: 1801;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #000; /* fallback */
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.overlay-content2 {
    z-index: 1800;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 1%;
    /* width: 700px; */ /* Removed this and added below code to make the content restrict within the visible area of fiddle.*/
    width:50%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow:auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 15%;
    /* left: 30%; */ /* Remove this line */
    /* margin: 0 0 0 -10%; */ /* add negative left margin for half the width to center the    div */ /* Removed this line and added below to position it in center */
    margin:0 auto;
    cursor: default;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}

.close-btn-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    /* width: 400px; */ /* Removed this line and added below */
    width: 50%; /* Make the width of this block same as the width of content block */
    /* left:25%; */ /* Remove this line */
    top: 15%; /* Add this value same as the top value of content block */
    z-index: 2001;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:1%; /* Added this line */
}

.close-btn2 {
    cursor: pointer; 
    border: 1px solid #333;
    background: #a9e7f9; /* fallback */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a9e7f9 0%, #77d3ef 4%, #05abe0 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#a9e7f9),          
color-stop(4%,#77d3ef), color-stop(100%,#05abe0));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a9e7f9 0%,#77d3ef 4%,#05abe0 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #a9e7f9 0%,#77d3ef 4%,#05abe0 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #a9e7f9 0%,#77d3ef 4%,#05abe0 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #a9e7f9 0%,#77d3ef 4%,#05abe0 100%);
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    position: absolute;
    /* top:30px; */ /* Changed the value to below */
    top:0;
    /* right: 180px; */ /* Changed the value to below */
    right: -8px;
    z-index: 2000;
    padding: 1%;
    margin:0;
}

.close-btn2:hover {
    background: #05abe0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.

This is so frustrating. It still doesn't work. The (X) Icon is offset way to the right and still moves when the window is resized...I'm at a complete loss right now...

Comment: Actually I take that back....I screwed up one on thing on my end...That actually worked, for the most part, the button still moves, but it is so slight you can barely notice it.  Thanks so much!!! :)

Comment: As well, the button doesn't move at all, that was just my lack of spectacles at the time.   Thanks again